# toUpperCase() issue when I map

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function that accepts a string and the string will be returned in a 'waved' version inside an array:

`wave("stack") => ["Stack","sTack", "stAck", "staCk", "stacK"]`

I wrote this code, but there's a problem when I have a doubled letter in the string:

```js
function wave(word){
  let arr = []
  word.split("").map(c=> arr.push(word.replace(c, c.toUpperCase())))
  return arr
}

console.log(wave("hello"))
```

`wave("hello")` gives me `["Hello", "hEllo", "heLlo", "heLlo", "hellO"]`

Notice that index 2 and index 3 are the same, index 3 is suppose to be "helLo", not "heLlo".
Why is that? How can I fix this?

Comment: i'd do this in a loop. it will make it easier than doing a replace. its due to the starting position and duplicate letters.

Comment: I think checking over the documentation on `replace` would answer this.

Comment: index 3 finds the first occurence of `l` in the word (which is 2), replaces it and stops there.

Comment: use a regexp for more precise replacement specification. or split the word into an array, replace one index at a time, and join before pushing into the result list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String.prototype.replace` won't work here as there are two same letters at different indexes so the `replace` would act on the first occurence.

We need to do it using indexes of each letter, which can be accomplished by `Array.prototype.map` where I get the index and use it to locate the letter to be upper cased:

```js
function wave(word){
 return word.split("")
            .map( (ltr, idx) => 
                     word.substring(0, idx) 
                         + ltr.toUpperCase() 
                             + word.substring(idx+1))
}
console.log(wave("hello"))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem happened due to the way the call of `replace` is being made. It was always replacing the first instance of `l`. The following code should work.

```js
function wave(word){
  let arr = []
  word.split("").map((c, i) => {
  let parta = word.substring(0, i);
  let partb = word.substring(i + 1);
  arr.push(parta + c.toUpperCase() + partb);
  });
  return arr
}

console.log(wave("stack"));
console.log(wave("hello"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using a `map` there is no reason to use `arr.push`. Secondly you can use `index` of the `map` function and string `substr` method.

This line will first create a sub string using characters from 0 till the index concat with the uppercase letter then remaining string

```js
function wave(word) {
  return word.split("").map(function(c, index) {
    return word.substr(0, index) + c.toUpperCase() + word.substr(index + 1);
  })

}

console.log(wave("hello"))
```

Comment: You're right I didn't notice that there's no need for push() because of map().

Answer (score 0):

index 2 and 3 have the same letter `L` and `replace` will replace the first matching value,

you can create an array of the length of the word and filling it with that word, then map it wo `upperCase` ease letter using `slice` :

```js
function wave(word) {
  const arr = Array.from(word, () => word).map(
    (w, ndx) => w.slice(0, ndx) + w[ndx].toUpperCase() + w.slice(ndx + 1)
  );
  return arr;
}

console.log(wave("hello"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a different approach and map the characters an check if the index match.

```js
function wave(word) {
    return Array.from(
        { length: word.length },
        (_, i) => Array.from(word, (c, j) => c[i === j ? 'toUpperCase' : 'toLowerCase']()).join('')
    );
}

console.log(wave("hello"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this in two parts. First make a function to replace a character, then loop through your string and update each character. Like this:

```js
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, replacement) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + replacement+ this.substr(index + replacement.length);
}

function wave(str) {
  ret = [];
  for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    ret.push(str.replaceAt(i, str[i].toUpperCase()));
  }
  return ret;
}

console.log(wave("hello"));
```

Comment: I like @ninascholz's answer. Much more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 0):

> Why my code is not working ?

When you pass string in replace function as pattern instead of regex, it just replace the first matching occurrence of that string, so in `hello` on index 2 and 3 same word is present so when you try to replace `l` it will always replace the first `l`,

---

You can create a replaceByIndex function and pass the value to it, to start replacing values from a particular string

```js
const replaceByIndex = (str, value, i) => {
  return str.slice(0, i) + value.toUpperCase() + str.slice(i + 1, )
}

function wave(word) {
  let final = word.split("").map((c, i) => replaceByIndex(word, c, i))
  return final
}

console.log(wave("hello"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with replace function. It will always replace the first occurrence of the character. You will need to write replaceAt function as shown in code, which will replace the particular index of the word. Hope this will solve your problem, happy coding!

```js
function wave(word){
  let arr = []
  word.split("").map((c,index)=> {arr.push(replaceAt(word,index,    word[index].toUpperCase()));})
  return arr
}
  function replaceAt(string, index, replace) {
    return string.substring(0, index) + replace + string.substring(index + 1);
   }

console.log(wave("hello"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also take advantage of the reduce method.

```
function wave(word){

    return word.split("").reduce((acc, cv, i)=>{
        acc.push(word.substring(0,i) + cv.toUpperCase() + word.substring(i + 1));
        return acc;
    },[]);

}
```